# How would you develop a frequency-sorted list of the ten thousand most-used words in the English language?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I was once asked by a current employee how I would develop a frequency-sorted list of the ten thousand most-used words in the English language.  Suggest a solution in the language of your choosing, though I prefer C#.

Please provide not only an implementation, but also an explanation.

Thanks

Comment: This site has your first 1000 covered: http://www.duboislc.org/EducationWatch/First100Words.html

Comment: Is there a given source list as assumed by at least 2 answers below? Or is discovering the list of the top 10,000 most-used words part of the problem for which you're seeking a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> inputList; // input words.
var mostFrequentlyUsed = inputList.GroupBy(word => word)
  .Select(wordGroup => new { Word = wordGroup.Key, Frequency = wordGroup.Count() })
  .OrderByDescending(word => word.Frequency);
```

Explanation: I don't really know if it requires further explanation but I'll try. `inputList` is an array or any other collection providing source words. `GroupBy` function will group the input collection by some similar property (which is, in my code the object itself, as noted by the lambda `word => word`). The output (which is a set of groups by a specified key, the word) will be transformed to an object with `Word` and `Frequency` properties and sorted by `Frequency` property in descending order. You could use `.Take(10000)` to take the first 10000. The whole thing can be easily parallelized by `.AsParallel()` provided by PLINQ. The query operator syntax might look clearer:

```
var mostFrequentlyUsed = 
     (from word in inputList
      group word by word into wordGroup
      select new { Word = wordGroup.Key, Frequency = wordGroup.Count() })
     .OrderByDescending(word => word.Frequency).Take(10000);
```

Comment: That can be very inefficient, because it's not parallelized.

Comment: Tens of thousand words is not something to worry about and btw, look at PLINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx

Comment: Where would you propose getting the source input words? That seems to be the toughest part of the problem, but you're taking it as a given.

Comment: @Dennis: That's tough. But I don't think it's not-programming-related. Wiktionary guys take it from Project Guthenberg text

Answer (score 2):

As a first cut, absent further definition of the problem (just what do you mean by the most-used words in English?) -- I'd buy [Google's n-gram data](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html), intersect the 1-grams with an English dictionary, and pipe that to `sort -rn -k 2 | head -10000`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use map-reduce.  This is a [canonical example](http://code.google.com/edu/parallel/mapreduce-tutorial.html) of a task well-suited for it.  You can use Hadoop with C# with the [streaming protocol](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/docs/r0.15.2/streaming.html).  There are also other approaches.  See [Is there a .NET equivalent to Apache Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339344/is-there-a-net-equivalent-to-apache-hadoop) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436686/-net-mapreduce-implementation.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to pop into my head (not syntax checked, and verbose (for perl) for demonstrative purposes)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %wordFreq
foreach ( my $word in @words)
{
   $wordFreq{$word}++;
}

my @mostPopularWords = sort{$wordFreq{$a} <=> $wordFreq{$b} } keys %wordFreq;
for (my $i=0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
{
   print "$i: $mostPopularWords[$i] ($wordFreq{$mostPopularWords[$i]} hits)\n"
}
```